# Java: discrepancy between message sent from client and message received at server

Tags: java, xml, dom

I don't know how can they possibly be different. The discrepancy is that at the client there are more spaces than at the server, so I get this when I try to parse at the server:
[Parsing DOM - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014970/parsing-dom-org-xml-sax-saxparseexception)
Here is the code, and the messages are included in the comments:

```
Element rootElement = document.createElement(MyServer.NEW_PLAYER_CONNECTION_REQUEST);
    Element participantTypeElement = document.createElement(MyServer.PARTICIPANT_TYPE);
    Text textParticipantType = document.createTextNode(participantType);
    participantTypeElement.appendChild(textParticipantType);
    rootElement.appendChild(participantTypeElement);
    document.appendChild(rootElement);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer;
    try {
        transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (TransformerException t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +  8);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
```

Comment: Sent to server: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><newPlayerConnectionrequest><participantType>1</participantType></newPlayerConnectionrequest>


Server received: <?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"standalone="no"?><newPlayerConnectionrequest><participantType>1</participantType></newPlayerConnectionrequest>

Comment: Please edit the sample XML into your question, the whitespace difference is difficult to spot in the comments. Also, include thr stacktrace you're getting.

Comment: How are you writing the XML string into the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suppose,but reading(more than conversion) between UTF-8 and other ASCii charsets can cause minor faults in character numerics reading/rendering through a stream. The charsets between the two points is likely the problem.